# Why is my IDdataErrorInfo validation implementation is not being picked up?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I've written an `IDataErrorInfo` class that provides some input validation. The problem I'm having is that it's not being detected at all, no validation is showing. **It used to work a few months ago.** I haven't changed any of the code relating to this validation class.

I've tried switching between Release/Debug, x86/x64, rebuilding/cleaning, deleting the shadow cache. Nothing has helped, unfortunately.

This is how I'm referencing my validation class in xaml:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Pharmatech"
```

The validation itself in xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path= (Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Calling it on the textboxes:

```
Text="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

My validation class is definitely under the namespace 'Pharmatech':

```
namespace Pharmatech
{
public class PatientValidation : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string _id;

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));

    }

    public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }

        set
        {
            _id = value;
        }
    }
public string this[string PropertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;

            switch (PropertyName)
            {
                case nameof(Id):
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
                        result = "ID number is required.";

                    else if (InputValidation.validateIDNumber(Id) != true)
                        result = "Invalid ID number.";
                    break;
            }
            return result;
}
}
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated - I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious.... or, VS is messing with me.

I guess it's worth noting that I've added the UI styling library Metro or MahApps recently. I've tried removing it, but to no avail.

Comment: Is the `PatientValidation` class a view model for your view?

Comment: Can you show bit of your databinding code (XAML or C#) to help understand the problem?

Comment: @SivaGopal adding an example. thanks.

Comment: @dymanoid I don't think so. It never was. How would I do this?

Comment: If this class has never been a view model you're binding your view to, then it has definitely never been working. The fact that you're using the `ValidatesOnDataErrors` property on your `Binding` implies that your view model has to implement the `IDataErrorInfo` for validation to work.

Comment: Is a breakpoint hit that is placed in DataErrorInfo indexer?

Comment: @dymanoid This makes sense. I'm still learning WPF and understanding MVVM. How would I implement this class as a view model?

Comment: You don't implement this class as view model. You implement the `IDataErrorInfo` interface **in** your view model.

Comment: What is the DataContext of your not-working TextBox?

Comment: First, you miss OnPropertyChanged in Id property setter. Usually, IDataErrorInfo is invoked as a result of PropertyChanged event or on initial binding (i.e. DataContext change). This is why your 'fix' from the answer works.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for everyone trying to help out here.

Although this may not be the best way do it following WPF and MVVM - I fixed it by setting the DataContext as follows:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:PatientValidation></local:PatientValidation>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Comment: Of course the binding to the source property must work the data to be validated...